# Am getting NetworkOnMainThreadException despite code not executing on main thread

Tags: multithreading, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use android studio to download a file from a Spring boot server. Here is the code:

```
private val viewModelJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

fun getCurrentDetailFile(detail: Detail) {
    uiScope.launch {
        val stream = detailsContainerRepository.downloadFile(detail.file)
        if (stream.success != null) {
            val wrapper = ContextWrapper(context)
            var path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            var file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            when (detail) {
                is PhotoDetail -> {
                    path =
                        wrapper.getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    file = File(path, "image.jpg")
                }
                is AudioDetail -> {
                    path = wrapper.getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    file = File(path, "audio.mpeg")
                }
            }
            try {
                path.mkdir()
                val inputStream = stream.success.byteStream()
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
                detail.file = file
                _currentDetail.postValue(detail)
                _goToDetail.value = detail
                doneLoading()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e()
                _errorMessage.postValue(R.string.error_load_detail_failed)
            }
        }
        if (stream.exception != null) {
            _errorMessage.postValue(R.string.error_load_detail_failed)
        }
    }
}
```

In spite of the fact that it is running on an asynchronous thread I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException when it executes this line:

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
```

I don't know why that is nor how to fix it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `uiScope` to me smells a lot like the main thread.

Comment: Modified the example somewhat so that it becomes clearer what `uiScope` is

Answer (score 2):

`private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)` is your issue. You probably should be using `Dispatchers.IO` not `Dispatchers.Main`. Even though your network call is in a coroutine, it is still running on the Main/UI thread (Main and UI threads are essentially synonymous).

Android will not allow network calls on the main thread due to the nature of not knowing how long or if they will complete. All network calls must occur on a different thread. Coroutines can be thought of as a job that is issued to execute in a specific context, and in your case, you said the coroutine should be run in the `Dispatchers.Main` context, which will run on the UI thread.

All of that being said, it might be worth while to ensure that wherever the network call actually occurs in code is on a background thread regardless of how that code is called. This would mean changing the method `donwloadFile` to launch a coroutine on an IO thread for example. The end result is that regardless of where or how the network call is triggered, you won't have it occurring on the main UI thread.